# Multiple row insert: Best alternative for INSERT ALL statement working on Oracle 8i

Tags: sql, oracle, bulkinsert, oracle8i

What could be the best and the most recommended alternative for the INSERT ALL statement shown below that is functional in Oracle 8i version? Its so very unfortunate that this particular statement is not working in 8i with its simplicity and readability. It would be great if you could provide some inputs. Thank you.

INSERT ALL Statement

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Also, it would be better if one of your recommendations is not the same with the query shown below for some reasons.

```
insert into pager (PAG_ID,PAG_PARENT,PAG_NAME,PAG_ACTIVE)
      select 8000,0,'Multi 8000',1 from dual
union all select 8001,0,'Multi 8001',1 from dual
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not simply write three `insert` statements? If wrapped in a transaction there is hardly any difference to the convoluted `insert all` syntax and it's also not really more to type. Also: why are you using a version that has been out of support for over ten years?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert these rows as a one transaction, do just:

```
BEGIN 
  SAVEPOINT some_name;
  INSERT INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n);
  INSERT INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n);
  INSERT INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n);
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
     ROLLBACK TO some_name;
     RAISE; -- reraise current error
END;
/
```

This simulates a behavoiur of `INSERT ALL`
`INSERT ALL` is a single command, so when some error occurs, then all changes made by this transaction are rolled back (see **Statement-Level Atomicity** here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e25789/transact.htm)